# Create Temp table, CTE and insert into Temp table

Tags: t-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In T-SQL, I am able to run and execute the following without issues

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE lmn
WITH CTEDefinition
 (
 select xyz from abc
 )
insert INTO lmn 
select from tables join CTE
```

But this seemingly simple construct is proving quite challenging to me. Can someone help with getting the right syntax for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Snowflake you could perform it is a single step using [CTAS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table#create-table-as-select-also-referred-to-as-ctas):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE lmn
AS
WITH CTEDefinition AS (
 select xyz from abc
)
select ... 
from tables 
join CTE
  ON ...;
```

Answer (score 2):

Snowflake has below syntax to use cte and insert.
Insert go first and then all cte and select clause.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE lmn

insert INTO lmn 
WITH CTEDefinition
 (
 select * from user_activity
 )
select from tables join CTE
```