# CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IN SNOWFLAKE USING CTE

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression, temp-tables

I am trying to create a temporary table in Snowflake using CTE. I will be using this table in the same session for another query.

Here is the syntax so far:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE NET_AVAIL AS (SELECT*
FROM CTE);
```

However, I am getting an error

> Syntax error line 7 at position 0 Unexpected 'CREATE'

Can anyone please help with this?

I would be using this temporary table in the second part of the query so should I also mention ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS?

Comment: there is no ; after LIST_ID='OT')

Comment: You don't need a CTE here. Why not just use a CTAS statement without the CTE?

Comment: [Create Temp table, CTE and insert into Temp table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77056952/5070879)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct order is:

```sql
create temporary table a2 as

with cte as (select 1 x)

select *
from cte;
```